# StringIO and String Import error on installing VIM-Latex via Pathogen

Tags: python, vim, latex, osx-lion, vim-plugin

I tried to install VIM-Latex using the Pathogen plugin on my machine which is running OSX Lion 10.7.5. I copied the downloaded VIM-Latex plugin files into my ~/.vim/bundle directory.

I also edited the .vimrc according to the instructions specified [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html).

However, I'm getting the following errors on trying to open a tex document in MAC Vim:

```
 File "/Users/username/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956/ftplugin/latex-  suite/outline.py", line 12, in <module>
import StringIO
ImportError: No module named StringIO   
Error detected while processing /Users/username/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim:
```

and

```
File "/Users/username/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956/ftplugin/latex-suite/pytools.py", line 1, in <module>
import string, vim, re, os, glob
ImportError: No module named string
```

Also, I ran a basic python script from the terminal that imported StringIO and string, and both seem to be getting imported just fine.

I'm not sure where the problem is here. Since I'm really new both with VIM and Installing Plugins, I'm not sure how I should go about debugging this issue, and so, any help will be precious!

Thanks!

Comment: vim can only run with either python 2 or python 3. It can not run both at the same time. Check that you have python support with `vim --version` look for `+python` (if you have `+python3` it means you only have support for python 3) if vim decides dynamically `+python/dyn` it will use which ever gets loaded first.

Comment: @FDinoff : I checked using the `vim --version` command, and found `-python3` and `-python`. So does that mean I have support for python 3 only? If so, how do I sort out this issue?

Comment: If both are `-python3` and `-python` python should not be enabled but it seems you have support for it. (My guess is its dynamic I wonder why its not showing up in version anymore). My guess is you have some plugin which uses python 3. If that is true you should disable it so python 2 get loaded first. (or python just isn't enabled)

Comment: @FDinoff: So, I had run the `--version` command earlier on vim by mistake and not MacVim. It seems like the problem happens only with MacVim. The .tex file runs fine on Vim. 
So I ran the `mvim --version` command and that seemed to spit out `+python` and `-python3`, which I'm guessing means that Python 2.x is enabled and but not Python 3. 
I tried disabling the only other plugin (NERDTree) I had (except Pathogen) and that didn't seem to solve it. So it looks like the problem is endemic to macvim. Any ideas on how I should go about debugging it?

Comment: I have the same problem. When I enter `:python import sys; print sys.version` on the mvim command line it reports "python 2.7.6", but when I try `:python import string` I get "ImportError: No module named string". So I don't think it's a python3 problem.

Comment: How do you install ViM? macvim-dev, home-brew, macports? I can tell that macvim from github or macports works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`StringIO` and `string` are not available in Python 3.x. To make this code work, you have to run it with Python 2.x, e.g. Python 2.7.

Comment: I was of the opinion that the OSX came with a Python 2.7 pre-installed. I confirmed the fact that this version of Python (that was pre-installed on my OS) was able to import StringIO and string by building a simple script at the terminal. So I'm not sure how VIM is trying to compile the two python files with a Python version 3.x. Any suggestions?